# PDF bookmark customization

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I've seen a couple of PDFs which have come of their bookmarks ("index" tab in most viewers) set either in italics, bold or both.

Googling around I found that the [`bookmark` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) is supposed to do this (I even used its `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` command to have a bookmark to an unnumbered chapter before the first part of the document appear as it should) but I find the documentation a bit confusing.

I tried setting the style for the bookmarks with either

```
\bookmarksetup{italic}
```

and

```
\bookmarksetupnext{italic}
```

but it seems nothing happens.

Maybe it's a viewer issue (I'm using Evince 3.2.0 under Ubuntu right now).

Has anyone succeeded in this? how so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.pdf) the font options for `\bookmarksetup` are `bold` (for **bold** bookmarks) and/or `italic` (for *italics*). There can be combined, if required. Here's an MWE with the output viewed in Adobe Acrobat Reader:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\bookmarksetup{bold}% Default bold bookmarks
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\bookmarksetupnext{bold=false,italic}% Non-bold and italic bookmark only for next sectional unit
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely a viewer issue then, since I ran your MWE here and got no bold nor italic bookmarks. The MWE itself is usefulf :)

Comment: The default PDF viewer on Mac doesn't display this kind of formatting. This is usefull with Acrobt Reader viewer and maybe others...

Comment: @projetmbc, Evince, Okular and Foxit ignore the formatting of bookmarks completely, PDF-XChange viewer honors the color specification only.