# Partial italic text in PDF bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bold, bookmarks, italic

In my LaTeX file I've got some chapter titles with partial italicised text. With the `hyperref` package, I get the required bookmarks, etc. but the style for these partial italicised text disappears.

Just wondering if it's possible to implement this? I've had a look at using the `bookmark` package, but I'm not sure which options (if any) to use, given that I'm not looking to have the entire text italicised, only bits of it.

Thanks for the assistance!

Here's a MWE that I'm running using `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\textit{Some Italic Text} and Some Normal Text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If anyone would be interested in putting a _complete_ bookmark in italics: see [PDF bookmark customization](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33277/pdf-bookmark-customization).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is impossible because the item's style is determined by bits in the integer F(ormat) key, introduced in the PDF 1.4 specification. The lowest two bits determine whether the entire entry is set in italic and/or bold. [Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf#page=586) (warning: 32MB PDF).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance and the reference! I'll add tags for 'bold' on my question in case any one is looking for an answer too.