# automatic PDF bookmark manipulation

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

This is a follow-up question to [PDF bookmark customization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33277/pdf-bookmark-customization)

How is it possible, to set in an report/scrreprt all chapters with bold bookmarks in the pdf bookmarks? I've found a discussion about it (in german: [renewcommand chapter](http://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/TF39SeBj/renewcommand-chapter-kommando-davor-und-dahinter-setzen)), however, the MWE from there is not compiling with pdflatex (TeX Live 2012)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex,open=true]{bookmark}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@chapter}{}
\let\@chapter\chapter

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar {\@chapter}{\@dblarg\@chapter}%
}
\newcommand*{\@chapter}[2][]{%
\bookmarksetup{bold=true}%
\@chapter[#1]{#2}%
\bookmarksetup{bold=false}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Test}
\blindtext
\chapter[Kurze Überschrift]{Lange Überschrift}
\section{foobar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `addtohook` helps:

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}<1 %
      \bookmarksetup{bold}%
    \fi
  },
}
```

Some remarks:

- pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected automatically by `hyperref` and `bookmark`.
- I have put option `open` in `\bookmarksetup`. This way `\usepackage{bookmark}` do not need options (reducing option clash conflicts).